# How to get response data in bootstrap-fileinput?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-file-upload

I use [bootstrap fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) to upload files to my server with ajax. The server gives back a json text as result. But I don't know, how to access it.

HTML:

```
<input 
    id="file-uploader" 
    name="files[]" 
    data-show-caption="false" 
    data-upload-url="dataProcessor.php?s=700" 
    class="file"
    type="file" 
    multiple 
    data-language="de" 
    data-min-file-count="1"
>
```

JS:

```
$('#file-uploader').fileinput({
    uploadClass: "btn btn-info",
    removeClass: "btn btn-danger"
});

$('#file-uploader').on('fileuploaded', function(event) {
    // event.data is undefined
});
```

Comment: Can't be answered with the input you provided, please elaborate. Provide the ajax call codes

Comment: I uploaded the question, with the full code

Comment: dont use event.data, try this function(data){ console.log(data);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event returns 2 parameters. `console.log` both of them to see what's included

Like this:

```
$('#file-uploader').on('fileuploaded', function(event, data) {
    // and check what's in both params
    console.log(event);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The json is in `data.jqXHR.responseJSON`

Comment: @IterAtor - no problem. please mark as answer by clicking on the check sign. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm this is correct. I've used this in a couple of my projects. You can access the `data.response` object, which should be the Json response object from the service/API - in a couple of my Json responses I'd included `{ "success": false, "error": "Darn it" }` as an example. Just to confuse matters there are also a few other properties - you could perhaps include this link to the documentation which lists them: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-fileuploaded

Comment: Not the question, the answer :D